# Karate framework text match startsWith as well as contains with OR clause

Tags: regex, karate, jsonpath, json-path-expression

I am parsing a response for all the names object and it returns an array

```
* def getName = response.source[*].name

And print getName
```

The api response looks like

```
[print] [
"Map of USA",
"Global map",
"Check map of RSA"
]
```

I want to match whether the getName[*] starts with 'map' or contains 'map'
by ignoring the upper case also. I am able to do the contains match using -

```
* def getLowerCase = karate.lowerCase(getName)
* match each getLowerCase[*] contains 'map'
```

But not sure how to put the startsWith condition also in the same line. Can anyone help me out with the logic. Thanks in advance !

Comment: I don't understand; If it starts with 'map', then the name contains 'map', obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
* def names = ['map foo', 'foo map', 'f map oo']

* def hasMap = function(x){ return x.startsWith('map') || x.toLowerCase().contains('map') }
* match each names == '#? hasMap(_)'
```